# Force numbers in list to two decimal places

Tags: python, list, formatting, decimal

I have a list of numerical data read from a GIS file (.shp):

`dataList = [4.98, 5.09, 5.23, 5.35, 5.4, 5.59, ...]`

I'm looking for a method that forces numbers in this list to display to two decimal places, with output like this:

`dataList = [4.98, 5.09, 5.23, 5.35, 5.40, 5.59, ...]`

The main issue is I'm displaying each item in a separate map document in a loop with the following:
`TextElement11.text = dataList[count]` which does not support the `"{:.2f}"` or `.format(5)` solutions I have found elsewhere.

The items in this list are for display purposes only, so it does not matter if a solution requires a conversion e.g. to a string.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your datalist and convert each value to the formatted string:

```
new_datalist = ["{:.2f}".format(value) for value in dataList]
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this initially but I think I used the same list, e.g. `dataList = ["{:.2f}".format(value) for value in dataList]`, which was causing errors. I'm not yet worthy to give you a +1 so my gratitude will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

Most Pythonic way to achieve this is using `map()` and `lambda` functions.

```
map(lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x), dataList)
```